# How can I add more ciphers in SSH?

Tags: ssh, openssh

I want to add  more international standard ciphers like in example Camellia or Gost

Now I only have the AES and Arcfour in my Debian 7 with OpenSSH_6.0p1:

```
# sshd -T | grep "\(ciphers\)"
ciphers aes256-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes128-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,arcfour
```

I'm surprised there is not a clear explanation in internet about how to do it.

What's the easiest way to include some of them?.

Answer (score 2):

> What's the easiest way to include some of them?.

GOST nor Camellia is not defined in the SSH protocol nor implemented even in the latest OpenSSH. If you would like to add it, you would have to write the specification for it and probably implement it.

On the other hand, updating your system to something newer (or at least installing latest OpenSSH from source), you will get for example `chacha20` cipher or others.

Comment: What do you mean by "write the specification for it and probably implement it"? Can you be more specific?. Thanks

Comment: The SSH protocol is defined in a series of RFCs and drafts: http://www.openssh.com/specs.html to ensure interoperability among different implementations. There is no specification nor implementation for any of your mentioned ciphers for use in SSH protocol.

Comment: I thought it was an international thing, able to include the different standards in the world.  Is this a private company?

Do you know if there is some alternative in linux to use the SSH protocol with some open software able to include  international cipher standards?.  Is there some guide about these alternatives?.  Thanks!

Comment: @Wandermore If there is no RFC for it, there is just no standard. Just because there is a cipher doesn't mean you can use it with SSH

Comment: I understand you. I'm a newbie with this topic but I would find amazing to know that the whole world is slave of using only these few ciphers with SSH. If what you says is right, then nobody can establish an SSH connection with a server using any standarized cipher. The whole world only use these few ciphers and there is not any alternative.   I don't have enough knowledge but I will wait for other comments. There are a lot of people and developers in the world.  What you says sounds too much orwellian to be real.  Some alternative should exist. 

thanks

Comment: No world is no slave of a few ciphers. As I already said, current version supports different ciphers that you can use, but not explicitly the ones you pointed out in your question. The AES is still the gold standard, but if you don't trust it, there is alternative. What you mean here with "standardized cipher"? AES is not standard for you? What is Orwellian about using standard secure ciphers? I really don't get where are you heading.

Comment: Regarding your mention of GOST, the Russian Linux distribution ALT Linux has implemented GOST crypto support in OpenSSH - http://sisyphus.ru/en/srpm/openssh-gostcrypto

Comment: @SimonKissane thank you for information that such things exist. Unfortunately this was never brought up to specification nor to official OpenSSH.